# Unale to handle Iframe contents in the real iPad safari browser

Tags: appium

I am trying to test the website in the real iPad safari browser. In that site, After clicking the button Iframe pop up is appeared. I can't handle it. I tried using the driver.getwindowhandles and driver.getcontexthandles, but no use.

Note: using the appium inspector also I can't find the Iframe contents.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you need to switch context to the wanted frame.

I know that in [NodeJS WD](https://github.com/admc/wd), you can use this function `frame(frameIdAsInTheHtml)` and from this moment on, your focus is on the wanted iframe.

You did not specify what sort of tools you use, so please add more information and tell me if it works